# Getting "HTTP_USER_AGENT:UserAgent" from server variables

Tags: http, server-variables, request.servervariables

Sometimes my application is getting `UserAgent` in the server variable `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. What does it mean and why it could not get my users browser information ?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the client set:

```
User-Agent: UserAgent
```

in the HTTP headers. That *is* the information that the client sent.

Comment: does that mean the client doesn't want my application to know such information ? I'm asking because I'm suspecting an attack.

Comment: We can only speculate on what the motivation of the person who set it was. There are any number of possible reasons. Concerns about privacy. Laziness. Concerns about being caught. Something else.